# I am trying to install mongo db on ubuntu and getiing this issue of unmet dependency

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, installation, mongodb-query

I am running

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb.org
```

Output:

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-database-tools-extra' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-server' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-shell' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-database' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-mongos' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-shell' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-database-tools-extra' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-server' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-tools' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-mongos' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-unstable-tools' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Note, selecting 'mongodb-org-tools-unstable' for regex 'mongodb.org'
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
> mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
> mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `gnupg` and its required libraries using the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnupg
   ```
2. Once installed, retry importing the key:

   ```
   wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. The following instruction is for Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic). For Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial), click on the appropriate tab.

Create the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list file for Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic):

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu 
bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
```

4. Reload local package database.
   Issue the following command to reload the local package database:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
5. Install the MongoDB packages.
   You can install either the latest stable version of MongoDB or a specific version of MongoDB.

To install the latest stable version, issue the following

```
 sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

6. Start MongoDB.
   You can start the mongod process by issuing the following command:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start mongod
   ```

If you receive an error similar to the following when starting mongod:

Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
Run the following command first:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: Same issue after step 5                                                                                                                         
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.